# If $G=\bigoplus_i\Bbb Z/p_i^{n_i}\Bbb Z$, then for which integers $r\neq\pm 1$ is $G=Gr$?

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, modules, projective-module, injective-module

Let $G=\bigoplus_i\Bbb Z/p_i^{n_i}\Bbb Z$ be a finite Abelian group with $p$ prime, $n,i$ integers.  For a fixed $r\in \Bbb Z$, let $f_r$ be a multiplication endomorphism on $G$ for which $f_r(g)=gr$ for all $g\in G$.

**Question:** Describe any possible elements $r\in \Bbb Z, r\neq \pm1$ for which $f_r$ is surjective on $G$.  In other words, for which integers $r$ is $Gr=G$?

**My attempt:**  Since any $r$ with a prime factorisation involving any of the $p_i^{n_i}$ will collapse some of the components the $\Bbb Z/p_i^{n_i}$, we avoid $r=\prod_ip_i^{n_i}$.

So we may stick with any  $r$ different from all elements whose prime factorisation is $\prod_i p_i^{n_i}$.   Hence for any $r\neq\prod_ip_i^{n_i}, f_r$ is a surjection of $G$.

My question is that, is that enough?  Is there any other better way of identifying such integers?

Comment: Do you need any help from us? If so, please tell us your exact problem. If you wanted to answer your own question, there is a button below which lets you do that.

Comment: I was giving my elementary attempt to the question and I am not sure whether my way is correct